# PYTHON: Appending converted continuous attributes (converted to categorical) to the original dataset using pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and I want to implement Naive Bayes Classifier using the pandas library. For this i want to convert all the continuous attributes to categorical and vice versa.

I am using the first strategy and i am trying to convert the continuous attributes to the categorical attributes so that there is consistency of data. The dataset I am using is the Income dataset available at : http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult

Now I converted the continuous attributes to categorical using

```
pandas.cut(X, bins, labels = None)
```

method. I used the equal width binning method to assign labels to certain bin widths.(example below). I stored it in a variable cat_age. Now I want to replace the age attribute in dataset with the categorical age attribute.

```
cat_age = pd.cut(age, [0, 25, 45, 65, 95], labels = ["Young", "Middle-aged", "Senior", "Old"], right = True , include_lowest = True)
```

But i am unable to replace the OLD age attribute values in the dataset. I tried using DataFrame.replace() and DataFrame.assign() methods.

```
pandas.DataFrame.replace(to_replace='AGE', value = cat_age)   #AGE is the column name in the dataset.
```

and

```
pandas.DataFrame.assign(AGE = cat_age)
```

but it is not letting me replace or assign different values to the column in the dataset.

```
The DataFrame.replace() method doesn't give any error but doesn't show the new values in the dataset either.
```

I am sure I am doing some Naive mistake. Can anyone suggest me a way that I am able to either append a new AGE column with categorical values or replace the old column with these new values.

```
old values are of type : int64 while new values are of type : str
```

This is just 1 column, there are other values in the dataset which i want to convert to categorical:hours-per-week, capital-gain, capital-loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you see 'pandas.DataFrame' in the docs that really means an instance of a DataFrame, 'df' by standard convention.  If you just refer to 'pandas.DataFrame', pandas has no way of connecting that with any particular instance of a DataFrame -- the dataframe instance is never implicit in pandas the way it can be in many stats packages.

Comment: Thank you. @JohnE. Now i know where i was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to replicate your problem. Your assignment approach looks very complicated. I think you just need to say `df['new_col'] = Series`

Anyway, the following works ...

```
import pandas as pd

# get data
from urllib import urlopen
page = urlopen('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data')
df = pd.read_csv(page, header=None, index_col=None)
df.columns = ['age', 'workclass', 'fnlwgt', 'education', 'education-num',
    'marital-status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'capital-gain',
    'capital-loss', 'hours-per-week', 'native-country', 'income']

# put ages in categories and add as columns to DataFrame
age_bins = [0, 25, 45, 65, 150]
age_labels = ["Young", "Middle-aged", "Senior", "Old"]
df['age_cat'] = pd.cut(df['age'], age_bins, labels=age_labels, 
    right=True, include_lowest=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mark-graph . Yeah I really did mean df'new_col'] = Series but just didn't know how to say it. Thank you once again.